# Winforms setup project force require admin privileges

Tags: c#, winforms, admin, setup-project

So, i have a winforms app, which my clients needs to install on their pc's (did this with Setup project). Upon successful installation, i'm adding some registries (needed for app to run properly), which is working as expected, tho, i need to run setup.exe (not .msi) file as admin

(

- Right click
- Run as administrator or
- Right click
- Properties
- Compatibility
- Run this program as administrator

).

This is ok on my local pc, where i've checked that "Run this program as administrator" property and it runs as admin all the time, but if i zip those files, and then unzip them (or when client unzip them) i get the setup.exe file with that property being unchecked again, which if clicked don't add those registries (which causes app to not run properly)

So my question is, how can i bypass all this and make setup project run as admin by default (without engaging clients to do/tweak anything)?

Hope this makes sense (if not i can explain a bit more, but it should),
and thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the app.manifest "Application Manifest File" with this element:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: I've tried doing this but (in my case at least) it's only for app itself (not for setup file) meaning i didn't get expected results (still need to manually run it as admin).
but thanks for answering!